# "Recommendation of" vs. "recommendation for" – what is the difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> - We are glad to provide a recommendation of a good work you did.
> - We are glad to provide a recommendation for a good work you did.

Comment: I would say, if you are offering to recommend someone to another person after they've done a satisfactory job for you: "We are glad to provide a recommendation for the good job you did." (You need the *a* before the word recommendation, and I'd avoid using forms of the word *provide* twice in the same sentence.)

Comment: As pointed out by JLG, the sentence has a few graver problems than the choice of *of* vs. *for*. I'd rewrite from scratch. Making this particular question obsolete in the process.

Comment: Indeed, the only meaning I can ascribe to the phrase _provide a job_ is _make available an opportunity for employment_, which doesn't seem to be your intention here. The second _provide_ is simply the wrong word - try _performed_ or _carried out_.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have corrected the sentences as advised. My question though still remains the same. If I want to praise a good work done for me and I want to use recommend word, how can I do it? Note, I do not want to praise/recommend someone. I want to recommend _a_ _work_ well done by someone, meaning,that I want to make an example from this work for others.

Comment: To *recommend* is to suggest, albeit with more positive implications. I can't figure what you're trying to say: "We are glad to provide a suggestion for the good work you did" just does not make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: No Martha, as per Merriam-Webster dictionary suggest is the second meaning for the word 'to recommend'. The first meaning is to say that (someone or _something_) is good and deserves to be chosen [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recommend). I want to recommend something, to say that something deserves to be chosen. Note, I do not want to recommend something to someone on particular, but just recommend something in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarifications, I think you can use 'recommend' in this way, but to make it sound more natural in SAE I'd reword your sentences to one of the following:

- We are happy to provide recommendations of X.
- We are happy to recommend X.

To my ear the second option using the verb form is more natural, and it doesn't require any preposition (of/for) before the object.  But if you insist on the acceptable *provide* + noun structure, then *of* is the preposition you want (meaning a good report of something).

In general, though, to "provide a recommendation" has a meaning that's more commending than suggestive, and I think that's why this structure is less preferable to just using 'recommend' as a verb if you're more just wanting to provide a suggestion.

---

A few other notes, though.  I switched *glad* to *happy* as that seems more natural in this setting, and your usage of *good work you did* is also a little awkward.  Better would be  *good work*.

In response to your second question to Zack above, I'd suggest "Please use this forum to recommend well done work."

Comment: Thanks MunchyWilly. I think your response actually answers my question. I need to use _of_ preposition, or more naturally use '_to_ _recommend_ _something_'. As I wrote in my last comment to Zack's response I will post here the link to the website that uses this sentence to explain what I mean precisely.

Answer (score 4):

I would also rephrase the sentence as suggested by comments on the question, but about the difference *in general* (note: suggested "more natural" phrasings are for Standard American English):

- If I provide you with a recommendation **of** X, X is a thing you can acquire, and I am endorsing your acquisition of it (generally in contrast to similar alternatives).  Example: you need a cleaning service, I provide you with a recommendation *of* a particular such service (perhaps the one I myself use and find to be satisfactory).

  This is more naturally stated as "I recommend X [to you]".
- If I provide you with a recommendation **for** X, the usual meaning is: X is something *you want to do* and I am recommending *you* to the people in charge of deciding whether you get to do it.  Example: you are applying to a graduate program, so you ask me (in the hypothetical, I am one of your professors) to write a letter of recommendation (of you) *for* your admission to that program.

  This one can also mean that X is something you have *already done* and, again, I am recommending *you* to some third party because of it. Example: you are leaving the company where we both work, you ask me to write you a recommendation (of you, to future employers) *for* your work there.  This meaning is more naturally expressed using a different word: I provide you with a **reference** for X.

Also note that "provide recommendation" is, in itself, incorrect in Standard American English: you need an indefinite article, "provide **a** recommendation".  I am not especially familiar with other Englishes, but I have the impression that omitting the article in this construction is correct in some subcontinental-Indian registers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Zack. I am interested in the case when I want to praise a work done by someone for me using word recommend/recommendation. How can I do it? Note, I do not want to praise/recommend someone. I want to recommend _a_ _work_ well done by someone, meaning,that I want to make an example from this work for others. Also, please note I do not want to recommend a work to someone else in particular. I want to recommend, provide a recommendation of a work for anyone in general, who might be interested in the same work, service provided in the future.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are making.  You want to recommend a work by a person to people who want similar work = is that not the same as recommending the person as skilled at this particular type of work?

Comment: I want to write something like this, – "Please, use this forum to give recommendations of the work well done." Is it grammatically, and stylistically correct? People on this forum have to write recommendations for the work they received not for the people that provided this work.

Comment: In SWE that is not how you would say that, and I am now more-or-less convinced that "recommendation" is *not* the word you want, but I'm *still* not sure what you really want to say.  It would help if you specified the type of work you have in mind -- construction? bespoke goods? assembly line? hotel reception? medical? what? -- as it may be described differently in SWE based on that.  It would also help if you specified your audience and your native dialect.

Comment: It can be a recommendation for any type of work (office work, construction, baby sitting, anything). My audience is North American, so the sentence should be written in standart English.   When the website that uses this sentence is released for public consumption I will post here the link to it and that will explain much better what I mean and want to convey. I guess the issue he is more in the semantics of the word recommendation then in style or grammar. Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think you may want to use the word **review** rather than **recommendation**.  This is the term used in many similar contexts, e.g. Amazon product pages have customer-written reviews of the product.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use specifically word recommendation. I will post here a link as soon as it is available to illustrate what I mean.